# Use multiple value for "size" validator in Laravel 5.3 requests

Tags: validation, laravel-5

like in title, is there a way to check my form value against two specific values? I need to validate a field of 11 or 15 characters, I wonder if I need to use a regex pattern or it can be achieved with "Size" validator.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation where i wanted to validate between two dimensions (height) for an image.
There are ways I guess of using custom validations for this as described in the following link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

But due to time limitations, i had settled with the following option of setting a between type of condition with the help of min_height & max_height. Agreed there is a loophole with this but it kind of was not an issue in my case.

```
'web_image'=>'mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|dimensions:width=1280, min_height=495, max_height=1706'
```

Hope this helps.